# Is there an alternative to duplicating the code below five times

Tags: groovy

```
         antBuilder.copy(file: lstFile, todir:srcDir)
         antBuilder.copy(file: lstGzippedFile, todir: srcDir)
         antBuilder.copy(file: tarFile1, todir:srcDir)
         antBuilder.copy(file: tarFile2, todir:srcDir)
         antBuilder.copy(file: tarFile3, todir:srcDir)
```

can i write the code above in 1 line by combining file parameters and todir parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just iterate over a collection of `file:` parameters?

```
def files = [ lst, gzipped, tar1, tar2, tar3 ]
files.each { antBuilder.copy(file: it, todir: srcDir) }
```

You *could* put it all on one line, but it's getting a bit long (TWSS):

```
[ lst, gzipped, tar1, tar2, tar3 ].each { antBuilder.copy(file: it, todir: srcDir) }
```